# Mysql dynamic variables against column name

Tags: mysql

How can I generate a dynamic variable with a column value? I got "S1" as value of a column, and I have defined a variable already as @S1, How can I access that variable using the current value of columnn.

example:

```
SELECT abr, @abr from table

         ^---- this doesn't exist, but instead of this I need to evaluate @S1.
```

Comment: Your doesn't make any sense can you specify the reason of doing that what exactly you are trying to achieve ?

Comment: I have some values for each record which is not in db and i need to check a > or <, So i thought this would be easy, also there will be morethan two records @MKhalidJunaid

Comment: Can you update your question and include sample data, table definitions and expected output in your question

Comment: im expecting abr would read as S1 and return 1 because the column abr is S1 in first row just like doing {} in php @MKhalidJunaid

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for row number:

```
SELECT d.*, 
       @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS rank
  FROM dummy d, 
       (SELECT @rownum := 0) r;
```

[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/724d6d/4)

Comment: it's not  row number bro, it's some random numbers @Brittain Ze

Comment: @RanjithM This gives you the same expected results you are looking for. Can you add more sample data please and the expected results.

Comment: @RanjithM See the demo in my answer.